Where should I ask questions about making music with Linux?
I have questions about using Linux (Debian) to make (professional) music.
I will change from Windows to Linux, because I like Linux a lot.
While migrating, I had many questions about integration of my sound card, the SSL-BIGSix Mixer, into the setup.
Also, I can't find questions about music software for Linux, like Bitwig.
In my opinion, it could be a new site like "Linux music studio" or something like this.

We have a music site which has a bitwig tag. Admittedly there are only 12 questions there but some of them do have accepted answers. Check their help first to make sure your questions are on-topic.
If you have more technical questions e.g. how do I get my soundcard to work then Unix & Linux is more likely to be what you're looking for.




Why does it matter that you are using Linux?
Then ask on:




I haven't gotten started yet, because all the software I can find is Windows-exclusive
Software Recommendations


I'm developing the software myself and I need to make a Linux-specific system call
Either Stack Overflow or Unix & Linux is likely appropriate, depending on more specific details of the question


My hardware isn't working properly on Linux or isn't recognized by the software
Unix & Linux


I ran into what appears to be a bug in the software or in a driver
Please don't use Stack Exchange for this; the same reasoning applies to other Stack Exchange sites as would apply to Stack Overflow. File a bug report instead.


I encountered a technical issue while using the software that looks like something that should be fixable on my end
Probably Unix & Linux, but Music might be able to address some things


I encountered a problem in the actual process of creating the music: either something to do with music theory itself, or something to do with the UI of the software (i.e.: it doesn't actually matter that you are using Linux)
Music



As a general note, there is also Ask Ubuntu for more specific questions. In your case, this won't help - Debian is upstream of Ubuntu. Ask Ubuntu basically only wants questions about how to "do Debian things" in Ubuntu, not about generically using Debian. But I'm including it for reference for future readers.

I wouldn't categorize questions that involve probable bugs as "customer service" (though I agree that raising issue tickets is good). how else would you ask how to work around a well-known, long-standing bug? or whether something is due to misconfiguration? see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417523/11107541.

@starball Questions about workarounds are really just generic how-to questions in disguise, with the caveat that the obvious approach is already known not to work. I don't have a better reference link for telling people not to post bug reports with the expectation of getting the developers' attention. If a post reads like a bug report but isn't intended as one, that's a clarity issue.

if it's written as a bug report seeking dev attention, then sure. a lot of questions about bugs are written by people who hit the bug and have no idea what's happening or what to do. I think those questions are okay.

There is also https://sound.stackexchange.com/, for questions about sound design.
